# How to parse a nested JSON with arrays using pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, arrays, json, pandas, api

I'm getting a JSON from the API and trying to convert it to a pandas DataFrame, but whenever I try to normalize it, I get something like this:

[image]

I want to archive something like this:

[image]

My code is currently like this:

```
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=True)

df = json_normalize(response.json())

df.style
```

The JSON is like this:

```
[{"transaction":{"client":[{"name":"Paul","category":"p","quantity":1,"price":{"amount":150.0,"tax":0.0,"totalAmountTax":150.0}}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and set the `record_path`

```
data
# [{'transaction': {'client': [{'name': 'Paul',
#      'category': 'p',
#      'quantity': 1,
#      'price': {'amount': 150.0, 'tax': 0.0, 'totalAmountTax': 150.0}}]}}]

pd.json_normalize(data, record_path=["transaction", "client"])
```

This prints

```
   name category  quantity  price.amount  price.tax  price.totalAmountTax
0  Paul        p         1         150.0        0.0                 150.0
```

Comment: I tried and I'm getting this error: TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str

result.style

Comment: @CED are you passing a string? you'll need to use `import json; data = json.loads(data)` first and then pass that to `json_normalize`

Comment: It worked! Thanks @cs95

What If I have other columns outside of that nested column that are not nested ?

Comment: Let's just say before the transaction.client you have "orders", "status" and "contract".

Comment: @CED can you open a new question with the sample data and expected output? And would you please vote on/accept this answer if it helped, thanks!